# MDA config file is invalid when I add pInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: .net, debugging, clr, windbg

I am trying to debug a managed heap corruption issue, and have resorted to using `WinDbg` and [`MDAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx) to get to the bottom of the issue.

However, as soon as I add `<pInvokeStackImbalance />` to the *.mda.config file, I get the error `The 'mdaConfig' configuration file is invalid.` This happens even if I use `pInvokeStackImbalance` by itself.

```
<mdaConfig>
  <assistants>
    <pInvokeStackImbalance />
  </assistants>
</mdaConfig>
```

WinDbg output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64
...
<mda:msg xmlns:mda="http://schemas.microsoft.com/CLR/2004/10/mda">
  <!-- 
       The 'mdaConfig' configuration file is invalid.
   -->
  <mda:invalidConfigFileMsg break="true" configFile="mdaConfig"/>
</mda:msg>
```

Other mda assistants seem to work fine, e.g.

```
<mdaConfig>
   <assistants>
      <callbackOnCollectedDelegate listSize="1500" />
      <gcManagedToUnmanaged />
      <gcUnmanagedToManaged />
   </assistants>
</mdaConfig>
```

I've read through [this](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/managed_debugging_assistant_configuration_files.html) and ensured that I have a space between the element name and the closing tag, and have arranged the elements alphabetically.

What have I done wrong with `pInvokeStackImbalance`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is evident from the debugger sign-on message:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 **AMD64**

Quoting from the MSDN Library article for pInvokeStackImbalance:

> The pInvokeStackImbalance MDA is implemented only for 32-bit x86 platforms.

In other words: you cannot use it to debug a 64-bit process.